# Redefing vars in body of with-redefs only and not in called functions

Tags: clojure

I am aware of how to use `with-redefs` to stub out vars when testing something, for example. I was wondering if it's possible to keep the re-definitions exclusive to only the immediate body of code such that it doesn't affect any subsequently called functions. For example:

```
(defn foo [] (println "foo")

(with-redefs [println (constantly nil)]
    (println "bar")
    (foo))
```

Prints nothing, but if it were possible to do what I'm describing we would see just *foo* printed, as `println` would retain its original value in the called function `foo`. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Why not just have `foo` outside of the `with-redefs`?

Comment: And if you want it to only effect function calls that are literally in the body, I'd just use the different function and not use `with-redefs`. I don't think you need mocking macros really if you aren't trying to mock function calls inside of other function. You might as well just call a different function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want just the opposite of `with-redefs` here:  plain old lexical shadowing:

```
(defn foo [] (println "Foo you."))

(println "to Foo, or not to Foo...")
(let [println (constantly nil)]
  (println "Foo me not.")
  (foo))
(println "...that is the question.")
```

with result:

```
to Foo, or not to Foo...
Foo you.
...that is the question.
```